# How to get the stream analytics output into multiple rows from single JSON(IOT HUB)

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics, azure-iot-hub

I have the data coming from iot hub and needs to be fed to the SQL table. 
The JSON data of iot hub looks like this-

[
{
    "DeviceId": "1",

```
"Parking1": 50,
"Parking2": 49,
"Parking3": 37,
"Parking4": 35
```

}, {
    "DeviceId": "2",

```
"Parking1": 45,
"Parking2": 54,
"Parking3": 37,
"Parking4": 35
```

}
]

---

And the table looks like this

---

DeviceId| Desc |Value

---

1 | Parking1 | 10

1 | Parking2 | 20

1 | Parking3 | 30

1 | Parking4 | 40

2 | Parking1 | 10

2 | Parking2 | 20

---

Need answers for the floowing-

1. So I need to write the query in stream analytics so that the query parses the JSON data and puts it in 4 rows of the table as mentioned above. Let me know what query needs to be written to get transform each key in every row of the table.
2. ALso the value of Parking1, Parking2, Parking3 and Parking4 should be inserted in Table when Device ID matches in the table.
3. Also everytime the values in the table should be updated not inserted.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have any flexibility in the way data is sent? If you can send parking information as a separate record, you can use GetRecordProperties() to transform it into the shape you need https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt270221.aspx . ASA doesn't support update for SQL output, you could add timestamp column and write a view to get recent value for a deviceId, parkingId combination if retaining all the data is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Going through your JSON, "Parking1", "Parking2", "Parking3", "Parking4" should be table columns.

Your select query should be

```
    SELECT DeviceID, Parking, Parkign2, Parking3, Parking4 
    INTO <SQLOutput>
    FROM <InputStream>
```

Also, as the input (iot hub) and output (SQL Azure) are different for an ASA job, data can only be inserted not updated.